# Create documentation XML without comments in code

Tags: xml, visual-studio, documentation

actually in my open source project I have thousands of documentation lines

for example

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the user can use the dialog box to define custom colors.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>true if the user can define custom colors; otherwise, false. The default is true.</returns>
[DefaultValue(true)]
public bool AllowFullOpen { get; set; }
```

and on some parts much more.
So I thoght, use the include to a xml file prevents this and I have just one line per property or method.

It now looks like

```
/// <include file='../Documentation/Services/ColorPickerViewModel.xml' path='Docu/Object[@name="ColorPickerViewModel"]/Properties/Property[@name="AllowFullOpen"]/*'/>
[DefaultValue(true)]
public bool AllowFullOpen { get; set; }
```

But its still too long for me.
So I ask, is there a best practice for include of documentation lines?

Its important for me that I have less lines in the productive code and xml files which can contain multiple objects.

(Is there also an include possibility of the license header text? I actually have a snippet I include in a region in each file)

Comment: If it is important for you to have fewer lines in the code file, then you will not want to use inline documentation. The whole point of inline docs is to keep the docs and the code together. I don't know why you're against that, because it really does help ensure the docs are kept up to date, but if you are, you need to look elsewhere. It is not a "best practices" issue.

Comment: I need the documentation only for generating a help file and help page using sandcastle. For use of the code its bad to have 20 lines of documentation above an interface method, so I have to scroll pages to find things. Not good for the overview.

Comment: The best would be I could remove all comments from the file and add it anyhow different - a question I had so far was a tool which opens each file, adds the documentation, let generate the *.xml file for sandcastle and stuff and then remove it back again. I need the documentation stuff only when I generate the documentation xml file. 99% of the time I look through the code I ignore all comments - annoying

Comment: Hmm, alright. I think you should [edit] your question to ask *that*, rather than about "best practices" for inline documentation. Chances are, there isn't such a utility, but I've been surprised before. Still, you're a programmer—it shouldn't be too hard to create a little utility that opens source files, pastes in the relevant documentation above the matching signature, then feeds the result to Sandcastle. The text-processing tools built into the .NET Framework would make this relatively easy. Or if you're a Perl/Python hacker/etc., I hear they've got really nice text slinging features too.

Comment: I did it on this way now, thanks anyway. I wrote I small tool which reads an xml file with all documentations from me and puts it to the sourcecode files. When I make the final release build I let the tool run, and after building all required files I make an undo on the changes. On that way I still build the documented source code files manually in VS and can have a look at the warnings if a comment is missing or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I make it with a tool now.
My original source has no comments anymore

```
public string Description { get; set; }
```

and I have a tool which reads the "documentation" xml file and this puts the comments in

```
<Docu>
    <File name="DW.SharpTools\Services\BrowseFolderViewModel.cs">
        <Item>
            <Compare kind="Contains">string Description</Compare>
            <Documentation>
                <![CDATA[
                /// <summary>
                /// Gets or sets the descriptive text displayed above the tree view control in the dialog box.
                /// </summary>
                /// <returns>The description to display. The default is an empty string ("").</returns>
                [DefaultValue("")]
                ]]>
            </Documentation>
        </Item>
```

1. I programm normally
2. Check-in all changes
3. I let the tool run which places the documentation code in
4. I do documentation adjustments if needed in code and documentation.xml
5. I build the release (and watch for warnings)
6. I undo all file changes

So then I have no files with 100 instead of 600 lines of code ^^